# Code Compare for Two Excel Files that contain Visual Basic Code

Tags: excel, vba, compare

Do you know of a tool that allows you to code compare two excel files (file1.xlsm vs. file2.xlsm) to see the code difference in the Visual Basic code?

I know that there is a tool called Beyond Compare. This lets you compare the contents of the sheets inside the two excel files, but I can't find a tool that compares the contents of the visual basic code.

Thanks
Neo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Beyond Compare actually has downloadable plug-ins to let you compare VBA between 2 excel files. :)

http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_moreformats_alt

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a copy of Beyond Compare handy, try VbaDiff. I built it for the purpose of comparing VBA code as you describe.

www.technicana.com/products/vbadiff.html